# ConditionalExpression DynamoDb Insert

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I have the below data schema for my DynamoDb table. I am trying to append list subscribers on the condition if input = name (ex: input = my-topic2). There can be many maps in the “topics” list and I need to search for the map where the name = input and from there add the subscriber to that topic.

```
  {
        “server-id”: “123345678”,
        “server-name”: “my-server”
        “topics”: [
            {
                “name”: “my-topic”,
                “subscribers”: []
            },
            {
                “name”: “my-topic2”,
                “subscribers”: [] //This is what I need to append on a condition that the input = “my-topic2”
            }
         ]
    }
```

I have the current following paeans I am using which appends “my-topic” subscribers.

```
params = {
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#T": "topics", 
        "#S": "subscribers"
      }, 
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":vals": [
          message.author.id
        ]
      }, 
      Key: {
        'server-id': serverID
      }, 
      ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW", 
      TableName: tableName,
      UpdateExpression: "SET #T[0].#S = list_append(#T[0].#S, :vals)"
    };
```